# Compile c++ code fails in cmd using cmake but works in clion

Tags: c++, cmake

Im building a game engine and would like to be possible the user to create his custom c++ code. In order to do that I create a submodule that would compile the code to a dynamic lib and link to the game executable.

Im able to compile the script module to a dll in clion but when I try to compile at runtime with `std::system("cmake --build ../../cmake-build-debug --target TechEngineScript");` it give me this error:

```
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Building CXX object TechEngineScript\CMakeFiles\Tech...TechEngineEditor\project\scripts\AnotherTestScript.cpp.obj
FAILED: TechEngineScript/CMakeFiles/TechEngineScript.dir/__/TechEngineEditor/project/scripts/AnotherTestScript.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1433~1.316\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DSCRIPT_BUILD_DLL -DTechEngineScript_EXPORTS -IC:\dev\TechEngine\TechEngineScript\..\TechEngineCore\src -IC:\dev\TechEngine\TechEngineScript\src -IC:\dev\TechEngine\TechEngineCore\src -external:IC:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include -external:W0 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /EHsc  /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DBOOST_UUID_FORCE_AUTO_LINK -MDd -std:c++20 /showIncludes /FoTechEngineScript\CMakeFiles\TechEngineScript.dir\__\TechEngineEditor\project\scripts\AnotherTestScript.cpp.obj /FdTechEngineScript\CMakeFiles\TechEngineScript.dir\ /FS -c C:\dev\TechEngine\cmake-build-debug\TechEngineEditor\project\scripts\AnotherTestScript.cpp
C:\dev\TechEngine\TechEngineScript\src\core/ScriptEngine.hpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'list': No such file or directory
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

My belive is that clion is using Ninja generator while cmake visual studio I tried to change using the command:

```
cmake -B cmake-build-debug -G Ninja
```

With this output

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31630.0 
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31630.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - broken
```

I tried to run the commands with the options that clion uses but gives me the same results.

Comment: Are you running script with msvc VARIABLE environment set (there are .bat to do that (vcvars64.bat)) See [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Allowing "custom C++ code" to be built and linked by users is generally a bad idea, and not really how modding works in "real" game engines. I generally better idea is to start with scripting, and only allow the users to use a very limited subset of functionality of your engine. There are a few common embeddable script environments that you could add relatively easy. Lua is one well-known such script language.